# Merge tags rsyslogd and rsyslog

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Can the following tags be merged please:

- [rsyslogd](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/rsyslogd): 6 questions
- [rsyslog](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/rsyslog): 5 questions tagged

Will this make rsyslogd and rsyslog synonyms?

(My first request. Let me know if I'm not doing this right.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you! I've merged the to tags, keeping [rsyslog]. I also created a synonym so that [rsyslogd] will be converted to [rsyslog].